# how to output all the iteration results from a FOR loop into matrix and plot the graph

Tags: matlab

I have two `for` loops in a nested format. My second loop calculates the final equation. The display of the result is outside the second loop in order to display when the second loop is complete.

Below is the logic I used in MATLAB. I need to plot graph of `eqn2` vs x.

```
L=100
for x=1:10
    eqn1
       for y=1:L
          eqn2
       end 
       value = num2strn eqn2
       disp value
end
```

Currently the problem I am facing is that value or output of `eqn2` is always replaced after each cycle until `x` reaches 10. Hence, the workspace table of `eqn2` and value only shows the last value. My intention is to document all the output values of `value` in every cycle of x from 1:10.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pseudo-coded a little too strongly for my taste - I have tried to reconstruct what you were trying to do. If I understood correctly, this should do address your question (store intermediate results from the calculation in array Z):

```
L=100
z = zeros(L,10);
for x=1:10
   % perform some calculations
   eqn1
   for y=1:L
   % perform some more calculations; it is not clear whether the result of 
   % this loop over y=1:L yields one value, or L. I am going to assume L values
       z(y, x) = eqn2(x, y)
   end 

   value =num2strn eqn2

   disp value
end

% now you have the value of each evaluation of the innermost loop available. You can plot it as follows:

figure; 
plot( x, z); % multiple plots with a common x parameter; may need to use Z' (transpose)...
title 'this is my plot'; 
xlabel 'this is the x axis'; 
ylabel 'this is the y axis';
```

As for the other questions you asked in your comments, you could probably findd inspiration in the following:

```
L = 100;
nx = 20; ny = 99;  % I am choosing how many x and y values to test
Z = zeros(ny, nx); % allocate space for the results
x = linspace(0, 10, nx); % x and y don't need to be integers
y = linspace(1, L, ny);
myFlag = 0;              % flag can be used for breaking out of both loops

for xi = 1:nx            % xi and yi are integers
    for yi = 1:ny
         % evaluate "some function" of x(xi) and y(yi)
         % note that these are not constrained to be integers
         Z(yi, xi) = (x(xi)-4).^2 + 3*(y(yi)-5).^2+2;

         % the break condition you were asking for
         if Z(yi, xi) < 5
             fprintf(1, 'Z less than 5 with x=%.1f and y=%.1f\n', x(xi), y(yi));
             myFlag = 1; % set flag so we break out of both loops
             break
         end
    end
    if myFlag==1, break; end % break out of the outer loop as well
end
```

This may not be what you had in mind - I cannot understand "run the loop untill all the values of z(y,x) <5 and then it should output x". If you run the outer loop to completion (that's the only way you know "all the values of z(y,x)" then your value of x will be the last value it was... This is why I was suggesting running through all values of x and y, collecting the whole matrix Z, and then examining Z for the things you want.

For example, if you wonder if there is a value for X for which all Z < 5, you could do this (if you didn't break out of the `for` loops):

```
highestZ = max(Z, [], 1); % "take the highest value of Z in the 1 dimension
fprintf(1, 'Z is always < 5 for x = %d\n', x(highestZ<5));
```

etc.

If you can't figure it out from here, I give up...

Comment: Hi i tried this it works. I am able to store values of "Z" end of every cycle  but when i plot it there was an error . I beleive it was because "z" and "x" are off different sizes .simple plots require x and z of same size . Any idea how to work arnd this ?

Comment: Try using `z'` (transpose) in the plot command. What is `size(z)` and `size(x)`?

Comment: in my case z is (10 by 100) and x is 10(1by1). I guess in the workspace the last value of X is registered .

Comment: Sorry i have doubt if i would to add a condition in the loop such that z(y,x)<5 for a given x, then output y.I used an "if" loop to set this conditon.so if anyone of the value drops below 5 . it should break and display the "y" The other condition i have is that i want to run the loop untill all the values of z(y,x) <5 and then it should output x .Could you help me with second condition ?and am i correct with the first logic ?

Comment: Appreciate your help so far. Thank you so much .

Comment: @CecilJacob - did the plotting work? Since x=1:10, which is implicit when you plot a 100x10 array, I think `plot(z)` should work (or `z'` I can never remember). As for the second question - when you say "it should break", do you want to continue again? In that case best compute all of Z, then print things out. `find(Z<5)` will return the index of all Z elements < 5. If you do `x2=repmat(1:10, [L 1]); y2=repmat(1:L,[10 1])'; ` you can then search for all x, y values where Z<5 with `x2(Z<5)` and `y2(Z<5)`. I hope that helps.

Comment: Plot works thank you . When i meant break , it means it should stop the loop and output(y).

Comment: Hi bro . I couldnt understand much of the steps you mentioned above . But intention in the first part of conditon loop is for given "x". Now only variable is only y and therefore loop should output the value of y for which z<5. Second part of the condition x is no more a constant , both x and y are variable independent of each other . I need to output "y" for all values of x gives z<5 and output the y and one more thing is there a way to start the loop from "0" , because matlab doesnot allow non integer .

Comment: thanks bro i appreciate your patience . Sorry for the trouble .I aint that gud with it . I will post my output screen. help to take a look at it . thanks

Comment: hi could i check with with you . what this error mean? "attempted to access s(2.25); index must be a positive integer orlogical

Comment: You are using a non integer as index into an array. If you notice, with the code I showed, I was using an array `x` that had non-integer values; I was accessing it with an integer index `xi` which __was__ integer (and thus could be used for indexing).  thus, x(xi) is valid syntax; so is Z(yi, xi); but Z(y, x) is not, as x and y are not (always) integers.

Comment: hi , difference i have is probably that L= 1.75 and y = linspace(1, 2*L, ny); where ny =4 ; The error i get when i do that is the "attempted to access s(1.8333); index must be a positive integer orlogical .error in eqn Z(yi, xi) = (s(x(xi))-4).^2 + 3*(y(yi)-5).^2+2.i have a sin function to determine the s(xi)=sin ((m*xi)/a)

Comment: The problem is right here: `(s(x(xi))-4).`. You are indexing s with `x(xi)` - which is a floating point number...

Comment: k thanks i got it .I changed s(x(xi) to s(xi).now my disp shows all the row num and colomn number where the condition is satisfied . Now i need to extract out the row at which all the colomns satisfies the conditions . if possible stop the loop and display the ' the sample has completely cooled '

Comment: If just before the inner `for` loop you set a flag `goodRow=True`, and inside the loop you set it to `False` if you fail your criterion, then you test the flag right after the inner `for` and break if it is still True...

Comment: Hi orignal condition was myFlag = 0; before the outside forloop and My flag =1 inside the If loop . So now it becomes goodrow=true & inside the for loop goodrow=false Hmmm..I hope thats what u meant .thank you

Comment: Notice - I said "when you FAIL" the criterion. If you want "the whole row is good", you only need to have one element bad. So you start with the assumption all are good - but the first sample >5 proves this is not the row you are looking for. Thus the logic...

Comment: Hi could i check if there is inbuilt fucntion to solve a quatric eqn ?. I generated plot and i used the plot tools to get a quadractic eqn for the parabola . i would to find the values of "x" when y is zero . thank you and appreciate your help

Comment: Cant you just use the pencil and paper approach? X=(-b+-sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a) gives the value of X where Y=0 and Y=a*x*x+b*x+c . There are built in solver functions but this is hardly the time to use them...